# Interval of θ for a Diagonal Line

Tags: calculus

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a couple of hours , but I'm just not understanding it.

The problem is asking to take the polar equation

$$r=\frac{4}{\cosθ + \sinθ}$$

and give an interval of θ in which the entire curve is generated.

I know that the equation ends up creating a diagonal line. But, how do you determine the interval for just a line? I think the answer is $0≤θ≤π$; but I doubt that's correct. Can anyone tell me what steps I should take to get to the correct answer?

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $\theta$ excludes those where the denominator vanishes

$$\cos\theta + \sin\theta=0.$$

They are $\theta =-\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$. Otherwise, $\theta$ assumes all values within these two bounds. Thus, its range is

$$ -\frac{\pi}{4}< \theta < \frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

Moreover, in $xy$-coordinations, the corresponding function is

$$x+y=4$$

which is a line with $-45°$ or $135°$ slope. As expected, they correspond to the bounds of $\theta$.

Comment: Seeing the process makes this problem so much easier to understand (and makes me feel stupid for not seeing the solution). I'll absolutely have a much easier time solving these types of problems in the future. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: No problem; you’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify denominator:
$$\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)+\sin\theta=\ldots
$$